# Download stock data from yahoo into R shiny based on user input

Tags: r, shiny, markdown

Got a problem how to download data into R shiny.

I have created a `selectInput` list with stock symbols like `AAPL`, `MCD`, `MMM` and so on with button Download data.

And I need to based on user input when is selected let's say `AAPL` to fetch the data from **yahoo** and i.e. create a chart.

I'm using `pdfetch_YAHOO()` function to get the data.

Can anyone give a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think Yahoo turned off it's API that did this back in May of 2017.  Here is an alternative way of downloading historical time series prices for equities.

```
library(quantmod)
e <- new.env()
getSymbols("IBM;MSFT", env = e)
pframe <- do.call(merge, as.list(e))
head(pframe)
```

Also...

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols(c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOGL"), auto.assign = TRUE, from = "2005-01-05",src="google")
```